# Extracting Contact Info Using Google's Places API in R

Tags: r, google-maps, extract, google-places-api

I have successfully been able to extract the business name and address from Google Maps using a city list and search terms. However, I am only able to get the name and address. All entries for the phone and website are returned as NA.

I had initially had an issue with a differing number of rows for each extraction and that is why there is all the length code in there. What is returned is just NA for the entire phone number and website column. Any ideas? Thank you.

```
library(tidyverse)
library(googleway)
library(RgoogleMaps)

# Set your Google Maps API key
api_key <- "My_Key"

# Read the list of cities from a file (assuming CSV format)
cities <- read_csv('My_Directory')

# Create a vector of search terms for shops
search_terms <- "My Search Term"

# Create an empty data frame to store the results
shops <- data.frame(stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

# For each city, search Google Maps for metaphysical shops
for (i in 1:nrow(cities)) {
city <- cities$City[i]
results <- google_places(search_string = paste(search_terms, city, sep = " "), key = api_key)

if (results$status == "OK" && nrow(results$results) > 0) {
# Extract the business details from the search results
names <- results$results$name
addresses <- results$results$formatted_address
phone_numbers <- results$results$formatted_phone_number
websites <- results$results$website

# Determine the maximum length among the extracted fields
len <- max(length(names), length(addresses), length(phone_numbers), length(websites))

# Create vectors with the correct lengths, adding NA if necessary
names <- if (length(names) < len) c(names, rep(NA, len - length(names))) else names
addresses <- if (length(addresses) < len) c(addresses, rep(NA, len - length(addresses))) else 
addresses
phone_numbers <- if (length(phone_numbers) < len) c(phone_numbers, rep(NA, len - 
length(phone_numbers))) else phone_numbers
websites <- if (length(websites) < len) c(websites, rep(NA, len - length(websites))) else 
websites

# Create a temporary data frame with the business details for this iteration
temp_df <- data.frame(name = names, address = addresses,
                      phone_number = phone_numbers, website = websites,
                      stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

# Append the temporary data frame to the main data frame
shops <- rbind(shops, temp_df)
}
}
```

Comment: This is interesting. What package or library are you using here?

Comment: Thank you for responding. Post updated and packages added.

library(tidyverse)
library(googleway)
library(RgoogleMaps)

Answer (score 2):

### If the field you want is not returned by Place Search, you can use Place Search to get a `place_id`, then use that `place_id` to make a Place Details request

After testing the library on my end, I found out that the `google_places()` method with `search_terms` uses the [Places API Text Search](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/places/web-service/search-text). Wherein its results only,

> return a subset of the fields that are returned by **[Place Details](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/places/web-service/details)** requests.

And if the **field** you want is not returned by **Place Search** it is recommended that you,

> use Place Search to get a `place_id`, then use that **Place ID** to make a **Place Details** request.

ref: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/places/web-service/search-text#PlacesTextSearchResponse-results

What that means is instead of using just the [`google_places()`](https://rdrr.io/cran/googleway/man/google_places.html) method, you can also use the [`google_place_details()`](https://rdrr.io/cran/googleway/man/google_place_details.html) method to fetch more details of the Place you have searched using `google_places()`, by fetching the `place_id` first. As mentioned above and also from the googleway library documentation itself:

> Once you have a `place_id` from a Place Search, you can request more
> details about a particular establishment or point of interest by
> initiating a Place Details request. A Place Details request returns
> more comprehensive information about the indicated place such as its
> complete address, phone number, user rating and reviews.

Here's a small example from the documentation:

```
## search for a specific restaurant, Maha, in Melbourne, firstly using google_places()
res <- google_places(search_string = "Maha Restaurant, Melbourne, Australia",
                     radius = 1000,
                     key = key)

## request more details about the restaurant using google_place_details()
google_place_details(place_id = res$results$place_id, key = key)
```

Take note though that the `google_place_details()` method from this library does not seem to have the [**field masking functionality**](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/places/web-service/details#:%7E:text=If%20you%20do%20not%20specify%20at%20least%20one%20field%20with%20a%20request%2C%20or%20if%20you%20omit%20the%20fields%20parameter%20from%20a%20request%2C%20ALL%20possible%20fields%20will%20be%20returned%2C%20and%20you%20will%20be%20billed%20accordingly.%20This%20applies%20only%20to%20Place%20Details%20requests.), so this could cost you a lot per request, since your place details request will most probably request all data fields.

What I can suggest though is to use [`google_find_place()`](https://rdrr.io/cran/googleway/man/google_find_place.html) method, since it supports the `fields` parameter which could help you fetch data that you only need.

I hope this helps!

Comment: Thank you. I started with the google_find_place() function but cannot seem to identify the website field. I've used fields = c("website") and it is unable to identify any information for each shop. Still working but if you have any ideas...

Comment: I got it! See my answer in this post. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to do it with the suggestion below. Here is the code to get the website data. It is really pricey though. Thank you.

```
# Iterate through each row in the dataframe
for (i in 1:nrow(shops)) {
  place_name <- shops$name[i]
  
  # Make a request to fetch place details using Google Maps API
  res <- google_places(place_name, key = api_key)
  res <- google_place_details(place_id = res$results$place_id, key = api_key)
  
  if (res$status == "OK") {
    if ("website" %in% names(res$result)) {
      # Retrieve the website URL from the result
      website_url <- res$result$website
      shops$website[i] <- website_url
    } else {
      print(paste("No website URL found for", place_name))
    }
  } else {
    print(paste("Unable to find website for", place_name))
  }
}
```